# Mac OS X equivalent of VirtualQuery or /proc/pid/maps?

Tags: macos

Is there any way to query the address space of a process on Mac?

On Windows, we use VirtualQuery, and on Linux, we parse /proc/self/maps (ugh).

Is there a system call or similar functionality on Mac?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `vmmap` command-line utility will give you this information. I'm not sure that the APIs behind it are public, though.

Comment: Awesome.  We're considering porting our binary instrumentation framework, DynamoRIO, to Mac, so we'd end up reverse-engineering a lot of the kernel-userspace private interfaces anyway.

Comment: Cool stuff... best of luck! If you haven't already got a copy of Amit Singh's "Mac OS X Internals", I'd highly recommend doing so.

Answer (score 3):

mach_vm_region_info can be used for this. See http://www.newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=12-1-vmmap.c

Comment: Please use links for reference only as they get changed with time. Paste the essential part of the answer here.